# Как сделать значение переменной неотрицательным

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная:

```
var smallChildrenActiveCheckbox =  
        $('.checboxWrap.w213').eq(1).find('input:checked').length - 1;
```

Какой функцией можно обернуть эту переменную, чтобы в случае если значение отрицательное, то переменной назначалось нулевое значение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let variable = -1;
console.info(Math.max(variable, 0)); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(smallChildrenActiveCheckbox < 0) {
  smallChildrenActiveCheckbox = 0;
}
```

Можно сокращенно:

```
        smallChildrenActiveCheckbox = smallChildrenActiveCheckbox < 0 ?
0:smallChildrenActiveCheckbox;
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так

```js
var p = (a => a<0 ? 0 : a)(22);
console.log(p);

var n = (a => a<0 ? 0 : a)(-22);
console.log(n);
```

Для вашего случая

```
var smallChildrenActiveCheckbox =  (a => a<0 ? 0 : a)($('.checboxWrap.w213').eq(1).find('input:checked').length-1);
```